# Javascript Fetching failing for no reason

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, express

I'm trying to make a login form where it fetches from another website, although, it keeps erroring with `Error: Failed to Fetch`

I don't really notice anything wrong with the code, but maybe its something related to CORS

Here is my code (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)

```js
// Values: UsernameVal is being tested as "Developer"
// PasswordVal is being tested as "AccessTest"
if (User.value != "") {
      if (Password.value != "") {
        setFormMessage(loginForm, "info", "Checking account credentials..") // Set form message is just a basic function to set a login status message
        var UsernameVal = User.value
        var PasswordVal = Password.value
        function a(data) {
          console.log(data)
          if (data.success == true) {
            setFormMessage(loginForm, "success", "Logging in..")
          } else {
            setFormMessage(loginForm, "error", "Invalid username or password")
          }
        }

        try {
          console.log(`https://mysite.repl.co/check?username=${UsernameVal}&password=${PasswordVal}/`)
          fetch(`https://mysite.repl.co/check?username=${UsernameVal}&password=${PasswordVal}/`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              accept: 'application/json',
            },
          })
            .then(data => {
              a(data)
            }).catch((error) => {
              throw new Error(error)
            })
        } catch (e) {
          throw new Error(`Error setting login form message: ${e}`)
        }
      } else {
        setFormMessage(loginForm, "error", "No password input provided")
      }
    } else {
      setFormMessage(loginForm, "error", "No username input provided")
    }
  });
```

This is the code on the other side (nodejs)

```js
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const fs = require('fs')

app.post('/user', function(req,res) {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "OriginForGettingData")
  const username = req.body.username
  const password = req.body.password
  res.send(`Added to login (${username}: ${password}}) list`)
  const table = require('./values.json').Logins;
  table[username] = password;
  const fileName = './values.json';
  const file = require(fileName);

  file.Logins = table;

  fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(file)).done(function writeJSON(err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
  });
  console.log(`Post recieved from ${insert}. New table: ${table}`)
})

app.get('/check', function(req,res){
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "OriginForGettingData")
  const username = req.param("username")
  const password = req.param("password")
  const table = require('./values.json').Logins;
  res.json({"success": table[username] === password})
  
})





app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

[image: Error]

/user and /check work fine, its just the fetching that fails

Comment: Can you share the full error you're getting in the `catch` block?

Comment: When it says that your coffee failed to fetch, they're must be some extra data included. I'm guessing though that is CORS...

Comment: The error I said is exact to what I'm seeing

Comment: I made an edit to the initial codeblock (first one), displaying more information

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the CORS for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from `OriginForGettingData` to `*`, it allowed the request to go through